# Google foobar Challenge EOFError

Tags: python, eoferror

I am trying to complete my first challenge on Google foobar challenges and I am stuck with an error which I can't seem to fix no matter what I do!

```
def answer(plaintext):
    plaintext = raw_input('(string) plaintext = ')

answer(plaintext)
```

I get `EOFError [line 2]`.

But, when I do this:

```
def answer(plaintext):
    try:
        plaintext = raw_input('(string) plaintext = ')
    except(EOFError):
        return
answer(plaintext)
```

then I get an error which says, all the test cases failed.

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing following:

```
return plaintext;
```

You have to return something after processing the input(s).

Comment: I think what you mean is **return answer(plaintext)**.

Comment: all of the test cases are failing because the answer() function must return some value so google foo.bar can verify against their answer and this return X statement is missing in the above code given in question.

Comment: @wontonimo you can see that there is a return statement but without actually returning any value so it is same as returning nothing.

Comment: Thank you for the response but I actually fixed that problem, a long time ago.

Turns out, you don't need any of the input lines or function calls in the program you write

You just have to complete the function's functionality to make the answer work

It was done